# Problem with Kibana login after set SERVER_BASEPATH SERVER_PUBLICBASEURL

Tags: docker, nginx, kibana

Hi I have configured kibana with SERVER_BASEPATH and SERVERPUBLICURL but I am receiving "GET /api/licensing/info 401" and the login page is refreshed and go back to login again

Now I'm trying directly, but the idea is to keep kibana behind nginx proxy, but with proxy and without proxy neither works, this throw the same message error

Here my docker kibana configuration

```yaml
  #Kibana
  kib01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.16.0
    ports:
      - 9201:5601
    environment:
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://es01:9200
      ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: '["http://es01:9200"]' #,"http://es02:9200"]' #,"http://es03:9200"]'
      ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME: elastic
      ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD: $ELASTIC_PASSWORD
      SERVER_BASEPATH: /dmckbnlog
      SERVER_PUBLICBASEURL: http://dmc.development.com:9201/dmckbnlog
      SERVER_REWRITEBASEPATH: 'true'
      SERVER_NAME: 
      extra_hosts: dmc.development.com
        - "dmc.development.com:192.168.1.188"
    volumes:
      - c:/data/kibana/kibana.yml:/usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml
```

kibana.yml

```yaml
#
# ** THIS IS AN AUTO-GENERATED FILE **
#

# Default Kibana configuration for docker target
server.host: "0.0.0.0"
server.shutdownTimeout: "5s"
elasticsearch.hosts: [ "http://elasticsearch:9200" ]
monitoring.ui.container.elasticsearch.enabled: true
```

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

For me the option was to use firefox instead Chrome, I don't know why but It is enough for me.

Link reference:
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/unable-to-login-to-kibana-on-chrome/96645/12

Thanks anyway
Best regards